# На чем писать сайт каталог?

Tags: веб-программирование, yii2, opencart

Имеется опыт в Yii2 и в принципе данный фреймворк мне привычен, и вроде бы есть готовые шаблоны для сайта-каталога.
Но в планируется интеграция с Яндекс.Маркет.
Знаю, что OpenCart удобен в этом плане, но не совсем уверен в его базовой защите в отличии от Yii2.
Хотелось бы услышать какие есть еще хорошие варианты, и определенные плюсы и минусы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если серьёзный проект пишите на том, на чем хорошо знаете. Я бы не очень сравнивал фреймворк с CMS, хоть схожести есть.
`OpenCart`  - мне нравится и не нравится одновременно. Качество плагинов(включая платных) не всегда соответствует мои ожиданиям. А если говорить точнее, практически всегда. Однако он имеет простую архитектуру и как по мне удобную. Также на нем уже есть рабочий механизм для работы с товарами.

`Yii2` - хороший и простой фреймворк для создания API(ИМХО). Если вы возьмете на frontEnd (`VueJs`, `ReactJs`, `Angular`) то может получится годно.

Если подвести итог, зависит от количество времени выделенное на проект и его качество. `OpenCart` - разработка на нем займет примерно в два раза меньше времени. Но также Вы получаете в комплект пакет не нужных модулей.

На `Yii2` - разработка и займет больше времени, но Вы сделаете полностью под себя. С OpenCart также можно под себя сделать, но теряет смысл его использовать.

Если Вы хотите сделать простой каталог, с Яндекс.Маркет без покупки и т.п тогда я бы писал бы свой. В Вашем случае `Yii2`